# How do I evaluate a string without using eval?

Tags: javascript, string, eval

Consider a string:

```
var a = '"Hello \\\\ World"';
```

This string physically equates to `"Hello \\ World"`.

Now consider another string:

```
var b = "Hello \\ World";
```

This string physically equates to `Hello \ World`.

In this scenario:

```
assert(b === eval(a));
```

How can I get the value of `eval(a)` without using `eval`?

Comment: Can you mention why you are avoiding `eval()`?

Comment: I'm not _avoiding_ it, I'm just looking for a way to do it without `eval`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to attack or anything (bad wording saying "avoiding"), but `eval()` evaluates general expressions. Trying to mimic its behavior completely would almost be like writing a compiler, your best bet would probably be to just mimic what you need. Write tests to see if the containing quotes exists, if they do determine if they are `'` or `"`, if not assume it is a numerical value and parse the arithmetic, etc.

Comment: Uh, that is the definition of _avoiding_. I'll ask again, why not just use `eval()`? It is the thing you want for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is your only goal to evaluate backslashes or there might be another special characters?